# Объясните по-простому что такое разыменование массива и зачем это нужно?

Tags: php

```
function getArray() {
    return array(1, 2, 3);
}

// в PHP 5.4
$secondElement = getArray()[1];

// ранее делали так
$tmp = getArray();
$secondElement = $tmp[1];

// или так
list(, $secondElement) = getArray();
```

Comment: Просто удобный и более быстрый доступ к элементу результата выполнения функции без создания промежуточных переменных

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Я уже было думал что это какой то заумный метод удаления ключей или что то в этом духе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Этот код из документации PHP. Раньше нельзя было написать

```
$secondElement = getArray()[1];
```

приходилось сначала присваивать результат работы функции переменной и уже работать с переменной.

Кстати, если элемент массива объект, то можно и так

```
$secondElementName = getArray()[1]->name;
```

А нужно это для удобства, меньше строк кода и понятнее сам код.